# Изъять id,динамически созданного инпута

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, события

Создаю input элементы динамически, а далее нужно вытянуть из них данные. Как быть, если создано сразу два или более input'ов? Мне нужно самому указывать id при динамическом создании?

```
<div>
  <button>Click!!</button>
</div>


$("button").click(function() {
  $("div").append("<input type='text' placeholder='first'>");
  $("div").append("<input type='text' placeholder='second'>");
})
```

Comment: что именно нужно вытянуть?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Создав динамически инпута, далее нужно вытянуть данные, а как если два три созданных?

Поставить на их (class) счетчик, вот так `first_0, second_1, ...`.

> Мне нужно самому указывать id при динамическом создании?

`id` это **уникальный** идентификатор, в вашем случае скорее надо использовать, атрибут `class`.

Вот так:

```js
var counter = 0;
$("button").click(function() {
  // Добави child в div
  $("div").append(
    $("<input/>", { // Создать елемент
      type: 'text',
      "placeholder": 'first',
      class: 'first_' + counter
    })
    // Добавить sibling
    .add(
      $("<input/>", { // Создать елемент
        type: 'text',
        "placeholder": 'second',
        class: 'second_' + counter
      })
    )
  );
  // Увеличивает счётчик
  counter++
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>Click!!</button>
</div>
```

---

**UPD:**

Использования `id`, в целом рекомендуется ограничивать.

Ещё один возможный вариант кода *без* счётчика:

```js
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Вариант без счетчика
//----------------------------------------------------------------
$(".addField").click(function() {
  // Добави child в div
  $("div").append(
    $("<input/>", { // Создать елемент
      type: 'text',
      "placeholder": 'first',
      class: 'first' // только class 
    })
    // Добавить sibling
    .add(
      $("<input/>", { // Создать елемент
        type: 'text',
        "placeholder": 'second',
        class: 'second' // только class
      })
    )
  );

})
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Пробегается по всем данным
//----------------------------------------------------------------
$('.getData').click(function() {
  var ar_first = $('.first')
  var ar_second = $('.second')

  $.each(ar_first, function(i) {
    console.log(i, $(this).val());
  })

  $.each(ar_second, function(i) {
    console.log(i, $(this).val());
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <!-------- Добалены классы -------->
  <button class='addField'>Click!!</button>
  <button class='getData'>Get data</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы пишете про то, что `id` — это уникальный идентификатор и нужно использовать `class`, а после этого навешиваете на `input` уникальный класс — нет ли здесь противоречия?

Comment: @ArtemKorsunov благодарю, ответил.

Answer (score 2):

> Мне нужно самому указывать id при динамическом создании?

Да, можно указать `id='something'` по аналогии с `placeholder`.

Также можно сделать вот так:

```js
var $input = $("<input type='text' placeholder='first'>");
// Присваиваем val для теста:
$input.val('test');
$('div').append($input);

console.log($input.val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div>
    <button>Click!!</button>
</div>

$("button").on('click', function() {
    $("div").append("<input type='text' placeholder='first' class='first'>");
    $("div").append("<input type='text' placeholder='second' class='second'>");
});

$(document).on('change', '.first', function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});

$(document).on('change', '.second', function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: В вашем случае не будут работать обработчики событий на `.first` и `.second`, так как на момент разбора html кода веб страницы и инициализации JS этих блоков не будет существовать. Чтобы обработчики заработали — нужно поменять их на:

`$(document).on('change', '.first'., function(){ ... });`

Comment: @sirWill, да точно, забыл совсем, поменял

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы вытащить значения у произвольного числа элементов, вложенных в другой элемент, есть циклы. Например, вы можете получить все `input` элементы внутри нужного вам `div` блока и с помощью цикла получить их значения. Как-то так:

```
var values = []; // сюда запишем значения из input
$('div input').each(function(el){
  values[] = $(el).val();
));
```

Вообще, для нормальной работы с `input` элементами следует использовать атрибут `name`, чтобы идентифицировать название хранимой переменной в этом `input` элементе. Атрибут `id`, конечно, используется для связки с тегом `label` и вообще хорош сам по себе, но при сериализации формы (автоматическом получении значений всех инпутов вложенных в тег `form`) собирается строка именно из пар `name=value&name1=value1&...` и т.д.

Поэтому, если вам нужно в дальнейшем будет передавать эти данные на сервер или ещё куда — то посмотрите на тег `<form>` и возможности jQuery по сериализации его полей ([jQuery.serialize](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83))